# Adobe CS 6 serial number

Tags: mac, adobe

I bought a used MacBook and the previous owner asked if I wanted Adobe CS 6 on it, so I said sure. I was wondering if there was a way I could find the serial number in the system files somewhere, so I can register CS 6 to my Adobe account.

Comment: You should contact the previous owner and ask for the serial number.  If it's a legal copy of the software, you can ask that person to transfer ownership to you.